# Intuition on $P_3$ and $P_4$-free graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

I am struggling to understand the structure of $P_3$ and $P_4$ graphs. Could someone provide me a few examples of graphs from each of these two classes?

Comment: Could you provide a definition of these classes?

Comment: Also, by $P_n$, do you mean the path with $n$ vertices or the path with $n$ edges?

Comment: Are you asking about $P_4$ graphs (body) or $P_4$-**free** graphs (header)?

Comment: A graph has no induced $P_3$ if and only if every connected component is a clique.

Comment: @AndrewUzzell In the graph theory books I've seen $P_n$ is a path with $n$ vertices, but I won't be too surprised if some authors disagree.

Comment: @bof Indeed, there are some references that use  $P_n $ to represent a path with  $n+1$ vertices. This phenomenon is evident in some literatures related to crossing numbers of graphs. https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05155

Answer (score 0):

First, I will assume for now that your **$H$-free graph** means a graph that does not contain $H$ as a subgraph. $P_n$ represents a path with $n$ vertices.

In fact, we only need to consider connected graphs since if a graph is not connected, it can be obtained by some connected components. First of all, any graph has a spanning tree. If a graph does not contain $P_3$, it means that its spanning tree can only be $P_2$ or $P_1$. We can easily see that connected $P_3$-free graphcan only be $P_2$ or $P_1$ as well.

Similarly, the length of the longest path in a spanning tree of a $P_4$-free graph cannot exceed 2. Therefore, its spanning tree is isomorphic to a star graph, and any edge cannot be added to the star graph. So connected $P_4$-free graphs are star graphs.

Indeed, there is another type of $H$-free graphs that are defined as not containing H as a **induced subgraph**. Under this definition, I am not clear whether the problem posed by the OP has some characterizations. Perhaps I will come up with a new question.

Comment: The graph $K_3$ is anot a star and does not have $P_4$ as a subgraph.  However, I'm guessing that the question is about forbidden ***induced*** subgraphs, since your interpretation trivializes it.

Comment: @bof Thank you for the correction, and I also agree with your point of view. I just looked up $P_4$-free graphs (forbidden $P_4$ as an  induced subgraph) and they are also called **cographs**, which have been extensively studied in many literatures, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cograph (including some linear recognition algorithms, although I haven't seen whether there are programs implementing them). As for $P_3$-free graphs (forbidden $P_3 $ as an induced subgraph), I haven't seen any specific terminology for them. If you have more information, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @bof I have senn your response stating that a graph is $P_3$-free if and only if every connected component is a clique. It is also trivial.